# Get Refresh Token and Id Token in angular app running inside microsoft teams using MSAL

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am using the [teams-angular github](https://github.com/sinedied/teams-angular) project to develop an angular app as a tab to run inside microsot teams.

When I am testing the angular web app as standalone in browser the application runs as expected and after successful login, the msal interceptor gets all the necessary data from local storage (access token, id token and refresh token are filled) and adds the correct tokens in header in order to call the Microsoft Graph API. When running inside teams, then only access token is filled but not id token and refresh token which are missing and interceptor can not get the required data.

Questions:
How do I get Id Token and refresh token?  Does icrosoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken returns only access token? Do I have to set Id Token and refresh token in local storage in order to make a successfull call to microsoft graph api?

The related code running in teams.guard.ts :

```
if (inTeams) {
            return new Promise<boolean | UrlTree>((resolve) => {
              microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
                successCallback: (token: string) => {
                  const decodedToken: { [key: string]: any; } = jwtDecode(token) as { [key: string]: any; };
                  this.registerTeamsTokenWithMsal(decodedToken, token);
                  microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();
                  resolve(true);
                },
                failureCallback: (message: string) => {
                  microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifyFailure({
                    reason: microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed,
                    message
                  });
                  console.log("notifyFailure: " + microsoftTeams.appInitialization.FailedReason.AuthFailed +
                              ", message: " + message);
                  this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;
                  resolve(this.router.parseUrl('/login'));
                },
                resources: [
                  'https://xxx.ngrok-free.app',
                  'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'
                ]
                });
            });
          }

private registerTeamsTokenWithMsal(accessToken: { [key: string]: any; }, accessTokenString: string): void {
    const accountEntity = this.getAccountEntity(accessToken);
    const accessTokenEntity = this.getAccessTokenEntity(accessToken, accessTokenString);
    
    const browserStorage = (this.msalService.instance as any).browserStorage;
    browserStorage.setAccount(accountEntity);
    browserStorage.setAccessTokenCredential(accessTokenEntity);
      this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0]);
  }


  private getAccountEntity(accessToken: { [key: string]: any; }): AccountEntity {
    const account = new AccountEntity();
    Object.assign(account, {
      authorityType: 'MSSTS',
      // fixed
      environment: 'login.windows.net',
      // oid.tid
      homeAccountId: `${accessToken['oid']}.${accessToken['tid']}`,
      // oid
      localAccountId: accessToken['oid'],
      idTokenClaims: accessToken,
      // tid
      realm: accessToken['tid'],
      // upn
      username: accessToken['upn']
    });

    return account;
  }

  private getAccessTokenEntity(accessToken: { [key: string]: any; }, accessTokenString: string): AccessTokenEntity {
    const accessTokenEntity = new AccessTokenEntity();
    Object.assign(accessTokenEntity, {
      cachedAt: accessToken['iat'],
      clientId: (accessToken['aud'] as string).substring((accessToken['aud'] as string).lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
      credentialType: 'AccessToken',
      environment: 'login.windows.net',
      expiresOn: accessToken['exp'],
      extendedExpiresOn: accessToken['exp'],
      homeAccountId: `${accessToken['oid']}.${accessToken['tid']}`,
      realm: accessToken['tid'],
      secret: accessTokenString,
      target: accessToken['scp'],
      tokenType: 'Bearer'
    });

    return accessTokenEntity;
  }
```

The related code for calling microsoft graph api in home.component.ts:

```
  callProfile () {
    this.http.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me").subscribe(
      resp  => {
        this.apiResponse = resp;
      },
      error => {
        console.error('error caught in component')
        console.log(error?.message)
        throw error;
      }
    )
  }
```

The configuration in app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.aadAppId,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${environment.tenantId}`,
        redirectUri: 'https://xxx.ngrok-free.app',
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      },
      system: {
        loggerOptions: {
           loggerCallback: (logLevel, message, containsPii) => {
               console.log(message);
            },
            logLevel: LogLevel.Verbose,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false
        }
      },
    }),
    {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read','group.Read.All','access_as_user','profile','offline_access','openid'],
      },
    },
    {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([
        ["https://xxx.ngrok-free.app",["access_as_user"]],
        ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me", ["user.read"]],
        ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups", ["group.Read.All"]]
      ])
    }
    )
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally in the console i Get the following every time I make the call:

```
    @azure/msal-angular@2.5.5 : Verbose - MSAL Interceptor activated main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-angular@2.5.5 : Verbose - Interceptor - getting scopes for endpoint main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-angular@2.5.5 : Verbose - Interceptor - active account selected main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-angular@2.5.5 : Info - Interceptor - 1 scopes found for endpoint main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - preflightBrowserEnvironmentCheck started main.js:169:37
[some-id] : @azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - acquireTokenSilent called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : @azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - acquireTokenSilent called for the first time, storing active request main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:acquireTokenStart main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback 2fcdf349-4ebc-4bad-a8a2-1b6b1a3fc81f: msal:acquireTokenStart main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - acquireTokenSilent - attempting to acquire token from web flow main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Initializing BaseAuthRequest main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Authentication Scheme wasn't explicitly set in request, defaulting to "Bearer" request main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - initializeServerTelemetryManager called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - getClientConfiguration called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - getDiscoveredAuthority called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Creating discovered authority with configured authority main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Attempting to get cloud discovery metadata in the config main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Did not find cloud discovery metadata in the config... Attempting to get cloud discovery metadata from the cache. main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Did not find cloud discovery metadata in the cache... Attempting to get cloud discovery metadata from the network. main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found 8 main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found 8 main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Attempting to find a match between the developer's authority and the CloudInstanceDiscoveryMetadata returned from the network request. main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - cloud discovery metadata was successfully returned from getCloudDiscoveryMetadataFromNetwork() main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found 8 main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found 8 main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Silent auth client created main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getAccessToken - No token found main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getRefreshToken - No refresh token found. main.js:169:37
[some-id] : @azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - SilentFlowClient:acquireCachedToken - No access token found in cache for the given properties. main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:acquireTokenFromNetworkStart main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback 2fcdf349-4ebc-4bad-a8a2-1b6b1a3fc81f: msal:acquireTokenFromNetworkStart main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Initializing BaseAuthRequest main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Authentication Scheme set to "Bearer" as configured in Auth request main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - initializeServerTelemetryManager called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - getClientConfiguration called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - getDiscoveredAuthority called main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Creating discovered authority with configured authority main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Attempting to get cloud discovery metadata in the config main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Did not find cloud discovery metadata in the config... Attempting to get cloud discovery metadata from the cache. main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Found metadata in the cache. main.js:169:37
[some-id] : msal.js.browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Refresh token client created main.js:169:37
[some-id] : @azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Verbose - RefreshTokenClientAcquireTokenWithCachedRefreshToken called main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getRefreshToken - No refresh token found. main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Info - Emitting event: msal:acquireTokenFailure main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-browser@2.35.0 : Verbose - Emitting event to callback 2fcdf349-4ebc-4bad-a8a2-1b6b1a3fc81f: msal:acquireTokenFailure main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-angular@2.5.5 : Error - Interceptor - acquireTokenSilent rejected with error. Invoking interaction to resolve. main.js:169:37
@azure/msal-common@12.0.0 : Info - CacheManager:getIdToken - No token found
```

Comment: Could you please refer below document: https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory/develop/refresh-tokens

Answer (score 0):

To get the access token and refresh token , follow this sign in flow:

[image]

please refer this document for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app#sign-in-flow

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is quite confusion as in other links the info is slight different. For example in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview. 
Please check this image https://ibb.co/VJMdjWb
Step5. Teams sends the access token to the tab app as part of the result object returned by the getAuthToken() call. 
Step6. .... The token returned to the tab app is both an access token and an identity token.